# How to extend base class which is extended already by different class?

Tags: php, oop, yii2

So I have a situation in an application where there is a CONSOLE app and WEB app.

Now if one knows Yii2 then he knows. There is

`yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php`

which is extended by

`yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php`
 ( FOR WEB in main.php config )

and
`yiisoft/yii2/console/ErrorHandler.php` ( FOR CONSOLE in main.php config )

Now here I want to override **handleException** function from **yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php**. Both ErrorHandler ( web and console ) do not override this method. This method is only in BaseErrorHandler.

So right now, I am extending both ErrorHandler from WEB and CONSOLE. 
So I do have to make same changes in two different files/classes. For it to work.

What if I just want to extend BaseErrorHandler and do changes in new class ( ONLY ONE class ) there and make it available in both classes which extends base class.

Comment: So you have written two classes MyWebErrorHandler extending ErrorHandler under web, and MyConsoleErrorHandler extending ErrorHandler under Console, right?
And now you want the same functionality to exist in both right?

Comment: if i understand correctly you need to extend all three of them in order to override the `yii\base\ErrorHandler` class's method `handleError()` to be effective for both the classes `console\ErrorHandler` and `web\ErrorHandler` so that they are extended from the Newly Written or **YOUR ErrorHandler** and the overridden method `handleException` will be effective on both of them.

Comment: @mrateb Actually MyWebErrorHandler extends yii2/web/ErrorHandler which extends yii2/base/ErrorHandler and MyConsoleErrorHandler extends yii2/console/ErrorHandler which extends yii2/base/ErrorHandler. Here I want to override method handleException which is in yii2/base/ErrorHandler.  I can do it. But I do have to have the same method in two different classes. one in web and one in console.

Comment: I suggest you try traits as written below :)

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I think the problem with this, is that if he created a class that overrides the original ErrorHandler he wont be able to access the functionalities that already exist in base\console\ErrorHandler and base\web\ErrorHandler.

Answer (score -1):

You can not have a class extending two classes. You can achieve what you want however through the use of **Traits**. **Traits** by definition from the guide [here](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/traits) is:

> "a mechanism for code reuse in single inheritance languages
> such as PHP. A Trait is intended to reduce some limitations of single
> inheritance by enabling a developer to reuse sets of methods freely in
> several independent classes living in different class hierarchies."

Practically what you need to do is create a **trait** containing the desired function with the desired behavior. Example:

```
trait handleExceptionMyWay { 
    public function handleException($exception) {
        //Put here the desired functionality. Example:
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

And then in each of your classes you should add the statement `use handleExceptionMyWay;` as such

```
class MyWebErrorHandler extends yii\web\ErrorHandler { 
    use handleExceptionMyWay;
}
```

This way the function that is defined in the trait is going to be used and not the original function from base\ErrorHandler